# Why does scan accumulator value reset when new subscriptions are created but not when using shareReplay(1)?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I wrote the following code expecting that the last subscription would print ['emitted value 1', 'emitted value 2'], but instead only prints ['emitted value 2']. This makes sense because BehaviorSubject emits the last value, but why does the scan accumulator reset to the seed value?

I've found that this behaviour is easily fixed by using shareReplay(1) but I don't really understand why. What is happening with the scan accumulator in both cases, using shareReplay(1) vs not using it?

```
const subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
const action$ = subject.asObservable();

const obs$ = action$.pipe(scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []));
// const obs$ = action$.pipe(scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []), shareReplay(1));

obs$.subscribe(res => console.log('first subs', res));

subject.next('emitted value 1');

subject.next('emitter value 2');

obs$.subscribe(res => console.log('second subs', res));
```

[This is the console output without shareReplay(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1F43.png)

[And with shareReplay(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKa8t.png)

Comment: so have you any questions about the answer below ?

Comment: No, I understand it now. The word cache helped me to see it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you subscribe to a `BehaviorSubject` you will receive the last emitted value. That's why you receive only : `second subs ["emitter value 2"]` in the console.

**shareReplay**

From [doc](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) :

> **Why use shareReplay?** You generally want to use shareReplay when you have side-effects or taxing computations that you do not wish to
> be executed amongst multiple subscribers. It may also be valuable in
> situations where you know you will have late subscribers to a stream
> that need access to previously emitted values. This ability to replay
> values on subscription is what differentiates share and shareReplay.

That means that you will receive all the emitted values without any calculation, it's a kind of a cache. This is visible in the console also, you have only one print that contains all the values for the second subscription :
`second subs [null, "emitted value 1", "emitter value 2"]`

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to an observable, it gets 'run' for lack of a better word. This can become kind of confusing as values are spread out over time, so we'll stick with synchronous calls for a bit. consider the following observable.

```
const getRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

const stream$ = defer(() => from([getRandom(), getRandom(), getRandom()]));

stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 4 6 2
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 4 4 2
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 1 8 6
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 8 6 7
```

Notice how every subscription is getting different numbers? They're all re-running `getRandom()` and their subscriptions get different values.

If we put an accumulator in `stream$`, each subscription would start with a fresh seed and get a result depending on what their stream emitted.

so:

```
const getRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

const stream$ = defer(
  () => from([getRandom(), getRandom(), getRandom()])
).pipe(
  reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
);

stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 12 (4+6+2) 
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 10 (4+4+2)
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 15 (1+8+6)
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 21 (8+6+7)
```

See how each subscription is not adding to the previous one? It's just adding up its own numbers.

They're not sharing accumulators or values or anything across different subscriptions.

So what happens when you use something like `shareReplay()`? In that case, instead of stream$ being subscribed to and 'run' 4 different times, it's just subscribed to once and it the results of that single subscription are shared no matter how many people subscribe afterward.

```
const getRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

const stream$ = defer(
  () => from([getRandom(), getRandom(), getRandom()])
).pipe(
  reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0),
  shareReplay(1)
);

stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 12 (4+6+2) 
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 12
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 12
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 12
```

Here, our accumulator only ever gets run once.

If you change it like this:

```
const getRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

const stream$ = defer(
  () => from([getRandom(), getRandom(), getRandom()])
).pipe(
  shareReplay(3),
  reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
);

stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 12 (4+6+2) 
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 12 (4+6+2) 
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 12 (4+6+2) 
stream$.subscribe(console.log); // 12 (4+6+2)
```

Then the accumulator is run 4 times, but `getRandom()` is only ever called to create the first 3 values, aftward each subscription gets the same 3 numbers.

---

So, to answer your question:

When you don't have shareReplay, each subscriber runs their own `scan` stream starting at the time they subscribe. **WITH** shareReply, the `scan` is only subscribed to once. You multicast those results to all future subscribers. That's the difference.